# How to read backtrace /memory dump from a GCC fortify crash?

Tags: gcc, gdb, coredump, memory-dump

I have an exe crashing from a fortify fail, I get the following backtrace/mamory dump.  How can I use it?  (GCC, Redhat Linux)

```
2*** buffer overflow detected ***: /apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82 terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7faa7a1967a7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x116922)[0x7faa7a194922]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x1158eb)[0x7faa7a1938eb]
/apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82[0x40853b]
/apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82[0x409fbc]
/apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82[0x40a7f0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7faa7a0a0555]
/apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82[0x401d79]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00423000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 101870038                          /apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82
00622000-00623000 r--p 00022000 fd:00 101870038                          /apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82
00623000-0062d000 rw-p 00023000 fd:00 101870038                          /apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82
0062d000-006f6000 rw-p 00000
```

Comment: When I see similar dumps in other posts, there is always something resembling fucntion namses.  WHy don't I haver that here?

Comment: Possibly  `mardb82` has had its symbol table stripped out. Can you show us the commands you used to compile and link it?

Comment: Actually addr2line gives filename/lineno function name  where it happened, on the machine where it was  built.

Answer (score 0):

Backtrace represents a [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Backtrace is generally generated by `backtrace_symbols()` from glibc https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/debug/backtracesyms.c .

> ```
> /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x116922)[0x7faa7a194922]
> ```

The current frame points into `/lib64/libc.so.6` file to byte 0x116922 in that file. That byte is loaded at address 0x7faa7a194922 inside running program address space.

> ```
> /lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7faa7a1967a7]
> ```

Same as above, but the offset if given relative to a function `__fortify_fail` defined in the file.

> /memory dump

The format of memory dump is explained [in `man 5 proc`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/proc.5.en) under `/proc/[pid]/maps` entry.

> WHy don't I haver that here?

Because debugging symbols are missing from the ELF files.

Comment: What I am interested in is the address. /apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82[0x40853b] (The last method in my exe). It's no way to figure out where this is, I guess?

Comment: Then please _be specific_ from the start. || `where this is` where is what? The address in program address space is 0x40853b and the file `/apps/suns/runtime/bin/mardb82` is loaded at 00400000-00423000, so it's byte 0x853b in the file.

Comment: What is interesting is the name of the top C functions in mardb82 where it crashes.  Ideally the exact location in the source code.  Knowing the C library function called and the content of parameters can provide some additional information.

Comment: Normally when I debug, I can see everything not optimized out (But with providing the location of sources).  -Og -g3 -ggdb3

Comment: Seems when eg  enter "break *0x40a7f0" in gdb, it know where it is :-)

Comment: Actually addr2line gives filename/lineno function name  where it happened, on the machine where it was  built.